# Enable Show Applications animation when triggered with keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome

When **Show Applications** is triggered with the Show Applications button in Dash, it presents the apps with a fluid animation.
But when triggered with the shortcut (`Super + A`), the apps appears instantly without any animation.

How to enable **Show Applications** animation when triggered with keyboard shortcut ?

Gnome version - 3.38